# What's wrong with my program which about Select sorting?

Tags: c

This is an example of a textbook. But when I verified the program, I found that the answer in the book was wrong. I can't find the wrong place for the code.
Thank you for your help!

I have already run the code. There are no syntax errors.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a[10], i, j, k, x;

    printf("Input 10 numbers:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        k = i;
        for (j = i + 1; j < 10; j++) {
            if (a[j] < a[k]) {
                k = j;
            }
            if (i != k) {
                x = a[i];
                a[i] = a[k];
                a[k] = x;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("the sorted numbers:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

The output is wrong.

For example:
Input 10 numbers:
1 3 2 4 6 5 7 8 11 9

the sorted numbers:
1 3 2 4 5 6 7 8 9 11

Comment: @James - post something that shows how all variables are declared and initialized and can be compiled and tested. We can not identify all problems leading to your incorrect sort without one.

Comment: It is still incomplete. There are no `#include`s and no `main()` to say the least. Please think about our situation: How should we run your code without spending extra time to invent this ourself? Please be so nice and give us the complete source. It is just a minute for you and will save in sum hours for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the swap check is in the wrong place.  It's in the inner loop, but it needs to be after the inner loop (but inside the outer loop).  The sort portion of the code should be:

```
for(i=0; i<9; i++){
  k=i;
  for(j=i+1; j<10; j++){
    if(a[j]<a[k]){
      k=j;
    }
  }
  if(i!=k){
    x=a[i];
    a[i]=a[k];
    a[k]=x;
  }
}
```

Notice that the `if(i!=k)` check is now after the inner loop, rather than inside it.

With the following input:

```
Input 10 numbers:
1 3 2 4 6 5 7 8 11 9
```

It now produces:

```
the sorted numbers:
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 11
```

Answer (score 0):

After indenting your code correctly it is clear: The `if (i != k) {...` is placed inside the loop. Put it one level higher.

Please adopt a good coding style (there are a lot) and stick to it. You will learn how many errors you will find with correct indentation.